# How to over come the error :- The `innerHTML` property is available only on elements that use the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, lwc-dom, visualstudiocode, lwc-oss

On click of a div i am trying clear the content and I am making it editable.
so when i try to get the innerHTML it has no issues
but when i try to modify the innerHTML , i get a console error as below in my salesforce local development server

[image: lwc:dom error on console]

So then i tried to add in the mentioned `lwc:dom="manual"`

I get an error like below

[image]

the javascript line caused the console error is event.target.innerHTML = "";

```
toggleEditable(event){
       
        //Remove the place holder text on click
        if(event.target.innerHTML == 'Click to enter the minutes'){
            event.target.innerHTML = "";
            this.cloneDefaultRow(this);
        }
        //Toggle editable to true for the clicked item
        event.target.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
        event.target.focus();
    }
```

I am not sure how to overcome this console error even though the functionality is not interrupted for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they don't want you to do that. I've been reading through the source and just happened to be at this section in [@lwc/engine-core](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/tree/master/packages/%40lwc/engine-core/src):

```
    innerHTML: generateAccessorDescriptor({
        get() {
            return originalInnerHTMLDescriptor.get.call(this);
        },
        set(_value) {
            throw new TypeError(`Invalid attempt to set innerHTML on HTMLElement.`);
        },
    }), ...
```

I'm not sure which file specifically though because I'm reading the compiled code.